# Change class color based on enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, enums

I have a Workout model that looks like this:

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :date, :kind, presence: true
  validates :template, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }

  enum kind: { other: 0, swim: 1, bike: 2, run: 3 }

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

In my view, I iterate through all workouts like this:

```
td
  .row
    .col-md-6
      = day.to_formatted_s(:short)
    .col-md-6.text-right
      = link_to 'Add +', new_team_user_workout_path(date: day, athlete: @athlete)
  - unless @workouts[day].blank?
    - @workouts[day].each do |workout|
      = link_to team_user_workout_path(@team, current_user, workout, athlete: params[:athlete]) do
        .workout
          .workout-kind.text-semibold
            = workout.kind.capitalize
          - unless workout.distance.blank?
            .workout-spec.text-light
              | Distance:
              | &nbsp;
              = workout.distance/1000
              | &nbsp;km
          - unless workout.duration.blank?
            .workout-spec.text-light
              | Duration:
              | &nbsp;
              = workout.duration/60
              | &nbsp;mins
```

If enum is 'swim' I'd like to add a class to Workout like this: Workout.swim. If enum is 'bike' the Workout.bike class should be appended, so I can change the background color.

What is best practice for doing this in Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like something for a view helper method... The basic rails approach would be to place a method in `./app/helpers/workout_helper.rb`. Or another common approach is to create "view models", e.g. with the [`draper` gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), so then you can define the method on the `WorkoutDecorator` class.

Comment: There's no single right answer for this, though. It really depends on what the tech stack of the application looks like... For example, many modern applications use a SPA front-end; in which case the mapping for workout kind --> colour will probably be defined in JavaScript, not ruby.

Comment: You can simply add the kind in class list, add css for different class , for an e.g `.swim {background-color: "#ff0000"}` `.other{background-color: "#f0f0f0"}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TomLord. In case I went for the helper approach, could you elaborate on how this function would look like? I'm still learning Rails atm.

Comment: Also, it should be said @TomLord that it's not just the 'swim' class. Depending if the workout is a Swim, Bike, Run or Other it should have a different background color.

Comment: @Andy you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan, good point. Done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the enum by using the "interrogative" way `object.enum?`, so you could do:

```
.workout{ class: ('swim' if workout.swim?) }
```

In case the workout isn't a swim, it won't print anything.

If you have a class defined for each possible enum, then you could do also:

```
.workout{ class: workout.kind }
```

This would work in case the class swim has been defined, and it takes the same name as the enum.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Sebastian. I'm assuming that I can just add to that line to check for multiple enums? .workout{ class: ('swim' if workout.swim?) ('bike' if workout.bike?) }. Is that correct?

Also, do you happen to know the SLIM syntax for this?

Comment: In such case `workout.swim? ? 'swim' : 'bike'` considering there are only two enum values availables. Or also just printing the kind value `workout.kind` it should print or "swim" or "bike".

Comment: Not sure, but you could try `div class=(workout.swim? ? 'swim : 'bike')` @Andy.

Comment: Actually really like your idea of just printing the workout.kind and appending that as a class. I'll see if I can make that work.

Comment: Great solution. I made it work by adding .workout class="#{workout.kind}". Thanks!